# Why am I getting this bash error when looping? It wont let me use C syntax

Tags: bash, loops, syntax-error, sequence

I want to print the numbers from 1 to 10. I am using the Terminal on Fedora 19.

My input is

```
 f((i=0;i<10;i++)); do
    echo $i
    done
```

The error message is

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: "f"? Are you sure that's correct?

Answer (score 1):

`seq 10` is probably easier than trying to use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
for i in {1..10}
do
 echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The others have pointed out your errors and gave you solutions.

```
for((i=0; i<100;i++))
for i in 'seq 100'
for i in {1 ... 100}
```

There are also other ways to do the loops. Thanks.